# Showing undefined variable: sendemail Laravel Beautymail

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

I cant send the email. It's showing undefined variable if I am putting "$sendemail = $insert->email;", but if I am putting email manually like "biswanath123@gmail.com" this one is working perfectly. How to fix it?

```php
use Snowfire\Beautymail\Beautymail;

function email($id)
{
    $insert = Clientdetail::find($id);
    $sendemail = $insert->email;

    $data = [
        'name' => $insert->name,
        'email' => $insert->email,
        'phone' => $insert->phone,
        'city' => $insert->city,
        'insurance' => $insert->insurance,
        'policyno' => $insert->policyno,
        'amount' => $insert->amount,
        'pdffile' => 'http://localhost/Bitu/insurancewebsite/'.$insert->filepath
    ];

    $beautymail = app()->make(Beautymail::class);
    $beautymail->send('emails.Admin.policydetail', ["data1" => $data], function ($message) use ($sendemail) {
        $message->from('babuli.prasad.singh@gmail.com', 'Insurance Website')
            ->to($sendemail, 'Insurance Website');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the variable within the closure.  The `to` method within the `send` function can't see the `$sendemail` variable without the `use` keyword.

```
 $beautymail->send('emails.Admin.policydetail', ["data1"=>$data], function($message) use($sendemail)
 {
    $message
     ->from('babuli.prasad.singh@gmail.com','Insurance Website')
     ->to($sendemail, 'Insurance Website')
  // etc
}
```

Assuming `$insert->email` is valid, this should solve the undefined error for you.

Comment: Tks a lot bro. Itz Working. I have a problem... How can I attach a pdf file with email?

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  To attach a file, use the `attach()` method within send.  Don't forget to `use` the variable for the file like above.  Check the Laravel docs for sending mail for more info - but it's pretty easy, just load the file, use it, and attach in the message.